# SSL Plesk CentOS, let's encrypt dosn't work

Tags: ssl, https, centos, plesk

I have 1&1 centOS ( 7.3.1611 ) Server with Plesk ( 12.5.30 ) and I install wordpress with Let's encrypt. But i can't go to https .
So, I follow all tutorial for that : install let's encrypt -> WebSites & Domains -> Let's encrypt -> install . After, I go Hosting Settings -> Security -> Check SSl support and select Lets Enscrypt

Impossible to use HTTPS for my wordpress and for control panel Plesk ( dosn't have check button anywhere )

Answer (score 1):

Don't you think, that it might be more helpfull to discuss your issue in the Plesk community at **=>** https://talk.plesk.com/

In addition, it would really help, if you provide corresponding logs ( Let's Encrypt logs AND domain specific log - files), so people willing to help you don't have to guess and have something to start with their investigations.

Comment: You are right for blog plesk, but I find my problem, it's the basic firewall of 1&1 can't open port for https